# Какой статус переменной использующейся в анонимном классе, взятой с полей основного класса?

Tags: java, классы

Вот к примеру код, в нем переменная `text`, используется внутри анонимного класса. Но мне не понятен ее статус. Она не `this`, ведь она не на полях этого анонимного класса. Она и не `super`, `Check` - не родитель. И не локальная это понятно.

Так кто же она? Как это правильно понимать?

```
public class Check {
    private String text;

    void method() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                text = "string";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Анонимные классы являются нестатическими внутренними классами для класса, в котором используются. А внутренние нестатические классы всегда имеют ссылку на внешний класс без которого не могут существовать, т.к. могут быть созданы только через экземпляр внешнего класса.

Доступ в внешнему классу из внутреннего происходит через `OuterClassName.this`. При этом, т.к. в общем случае `this` можно опустить если нет конфликтов имён методов внутреннего и внешнего классов, то `OuterClassName.this` опускается и, таким образом, обращение к вашей переменной `text` внешнего класса происходит просто по её имени.

Т.е. в вашем случае приведённый ниже код - идентичен:

```
text = "string";
Check.this.text = "string";
```

---

Если же у вас во внутреннем классе была бы объявлена переменная с таким же именем как и во внешнем, то обращаться к переменной внешнего класса надо уже обязательно через ссылку на него. Пример:

```
public class Check {
    private String text;

    void method() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            private String text;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //поле анонимного класса
                text = "string";
                //поле внешнего класса
                Check.this.text = "string";
            }
        });
    }
}
```